# How to integrate vertical scroll to Bootstrap Datatable using slimscroll

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
$("#tbllistOPDetails").DataTable({
    "scrollY": "250px",
    "scrollX": true,
    "paging": true,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "searching": false,
    "orderCellsTop": true,
    "info": true,
    "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
        $('.dataTables_scrollBody').slimScroll({
            height: "250px",
            alwaysVisible: true
        });
    }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32PWm.png)

the above code is for scroll horizontal in datatable using slimscroll, but i dont know how to give vertically scroll using slim scroll please help me. And i put a image of the slim scroll using datatable in below.

Comment: Do you really need a horizontal scroll ? As Datatable is responsive it will adjust to to your screen width with attribute `width : 100%` .

Comment: "enter image description here"

Comment: hi Prakash Theta -) i already use width 100% but it not happen

Comment: hi, Brandon Ibbotson hear(enter image description here) the image i will put that link click on it. and see what i am want?

Comment: Can you please create JSFiddle of your code if possible? So that people can have a look at your problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ns05w9xn/2/ link for vertical scroll, i also want horizontal scroll also

Comment: sorry i want horizontal scroll..

Answer (score 0):

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/ns05w9xn/5/

I have not added an horizontal scroll for your DataTable, but I have fixed the width problem(**I think** if table width is fixed you do not need an horizontal scroll) with below css property

```
table{
  width: 100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

And change the table `HTML` (removing the classes applied)as below

```
<table id="example">
....
</table>
```

Below is the `JS` code (In simplest form you can add your attributes to it)

```
 $('#example').DataTable( {
        "sScrollY": 200,  
        "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
            $('.dataTables_scrollBody').slimScroll({
                height: "200px",
                alwaysVisible: true
            });
        }
  });
```

Note : If you need an horizontal scroll anyway (I don't think you need it when width is fixed), please comment below I will try to solve it.

Comment: i already got vertically scroll, i want horizontal scroll please help me. in the above jsfiddel link doesn't show horizontal scroll please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tbllistOPDetails").DataTable({
    "scrollY": "250px",
    "scrollX": true,
    "paging": true,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "searching": false,
   "sScrollXInner": "2000px", //for horizontal scrolling 
    "orderCellsTop": true,
    "info": true,
    "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
        $('.dataTables_scrollBody').slimScroll({
            height: "250px",
            alwaysVisible: true
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tbllistOPDetails").DataTable({
    "scrollY": "250px",
    "scrollX": true,
    "paging": true,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "searching": false,
   "sScrollXInner": "2000px", //for horizontal scrolling 
    "orderCellsTop": true,
    "info": true,
    "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
        $('.dataTables_scrollBody').slimScroll({
            height: "250px",
            width: '100%',
            axis: 'both',
            alwaysVisible: true
        });
    }
});
```